# MVC dynamic url template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am asking this question out of curiosity.  I have seen few sites implemented using MVC technology and has url formate as below.

```
http://companyname/Request/{requestnumber}/Updte
```

In above example Request is a controller and Updte is an action.  Can someone help me what should we put inside RegisterRoute to achive this.

I tried below code but its not working.

```
routes.MapRoute("testMap",
                url: "{controller}/{*}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller="Home",action="Test"}
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute("testMap",
                    url: "{controller}/{requestnumber}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Test", requestnumber =RouteParameter.Optional}
                    );
```

you can remove `RouteParameter.Optional`, if it is a mandatory candidate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
routes.MapRoute("testMap",
            url: "{controller}/{reqNumber}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller="Home",action="Test", reqNumber = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```